# Closed set minus an open set.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

If $A= [0,1]\cup[2,3]\cup \{4\}$ and $B= (0,1)\cup(2,3)$

What would $A\setminus B$ be?

I believe the answer would be $\{4\}$ but I think I may be wrong....

Comment: $4$ is in $A\setminus B$, but so are four other points. What is $[0,1]\setminus(0,1)$?

Comment: ....is it {0,1}

Comment: It is indeed. Now apply that to the rest of $A\setminus B$, and you’ll be in business.

Comment: 0,1 2 and 3 should be in, shouldn'shouldn't they.  After all, 0 1 2 and 3 are all in A but not in B, so the must be in A\ B.